# Image's given path format not supported

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, format, save

I have a program that saves images, but when I debug it I get this error:

> The given path's format is not supported.

I want to know why it is not supported, and how to fix this issue. Thanks in advance

### My Code

```
BitmapSource image = BitmapSource.Create(colorFrame.Width, colorFrame.Height, 
                     96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, pixels, stride);

ImageFormat format = ImageFormat.Jpeg;

string file_name = "C:\\Kinected\\Images\\Kinect" + bb1 + ".jpg";

image.Save(file_name, format);
```

#### Edit

I have added the code, and it compiles correctly, but the file never saves. Here's the code:

```
string mypath = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"C:\", "Kinected", "Images");
if (!Directory.Exists(mypath))
  {
       Directory.CreateDirectory(mypath);
       file_name = System.IO.Path.Combine(mypath, "Kinect 1" + bb1 + ".jpeg");
  }

if (file_name == null)
 {
       return;
 }

if (!Directory.Exists(file_name))
 {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(file_name);
 }
```

#### Edit

I have added all of the below code, but I still get the `The given path's format is not supported.` error. Thanks again.

```
BitmapSource image = BitmapSource.Create(
                colorFrame.Width, colorFrame.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, pixels, stride);

            totalFrames = colorFrame.FrameNumber;
            ImageFormat format = ImageFormat.Jpeg;                

            if (PersonDetected == true)
            {
                if (!Directory.Exists(mypath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(mypath);
                    file_name = "C:\\Kinected\\Images\\Kinect 1 " + bb1 + ".jpeg";
                }
                if (file_name == null || mypath == null || image == null)
                {
                    if (mypath == null)
                    {
                        mypath = System.IO.Path.Combine("D:/", "Kinected", "Images");

                        if (!Directory.Exists(mypath))
                        {
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(mypath);
                        }
                    }

                    if (file_name == null)
                    {
                        file_name = "D:\\Kinected\\Images\\Kinect " + bb1 + ".jpeg";
                    }

                    if (image == null)
                    {
                        image = BitmapSource.Create(
                                     colorFrame.Width, colorFrame.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, pixels, stride);
                    }
                }

                if (totalFrames % 10 == 0)
                {
                    if (file_name != null && image != null && format != null)
                    {
                        image.Save(file_name, format);//where I get the error
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Maybe this will help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348768/the-given-paths-format-is-not-supported-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always make path like

```
string mypath = Path.Combine(@"C:\", "Kinected", "Images");
```

There are quite a few areas from where this problem is generated.

**1. Make sure that path is created.**

```
if(!Directory.Exists(mypath))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(mypath);
```

**2. Maybe directory is already created but you do not have rights being C:. Change C: to D:**

```
string file_name = Path.Combine(@"D:\", "Kinect" + bb1 + ".jpg");
```

Now check if it created there.

Read more on this [Save Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh.aspx).

Comment: Lol I'll change `file_name` to what it actually , check edits

Comment: I got the error: `The device is not ready` on `Directory.CreateDirectory(mypath);`

Comment: @OutlawLemur: Why this line ? `Directory.CreateDirectory(file_name);` this line will not create directory. This is your total file path which include file name also. `Directory.CreateDirectory` work on directory path not on file paths. and try changing path of C: to D:. May be rights are the issue.

Comment: I didnt include the image.Save because it didn't change from last time. Also when I use D: it gives an error, and I have done this before with it working with C:

Comment: The directory exists, and I have used C: and D:, but the format is not supported, not the path

Comment: Do you have TeamViewer? I can help you that way.

Comment: Ok Ill create a room, It's called "Room for Outlaw Lemur and Nikhil Agrawal"

Comment: Currently it saves fine, but when I use `D:` or `C:`, it doesn't appear in my Directory, why?

Answer (score -1):

Try using a filename:

```
string file_name = "c:\\example\\path\\afile.jpg";
```

Comment: Lol I'll change `file_name` to what it actually is, check edits