# Error: An error occurred with the following error message: "The given path's format is not supported."

Tags: ssis

Im very new to SSIS. My problem is this:

`[File System Task] Error: An error occurred with the following error message: "The given path's format is not supported.".`

This relates to a variable that is being taken from a recordset.
The recordset takes a list of filepaths from a table in a database, I have then have a ForEach Loop container with the offending File System Task inside it.

Using Breakpoints I have established that when the path is mapped to the variable all of the backslashes are duplicated, could this be the problem or is there something else I'm missing?

Thanks for any help

Comment: "all of the backslashes are duplicated" so `\\server\share\path\myfile.txt` is displayed in SSIS as `\\\\server\\share\\path\\myfile.txt`? That's simply an artifact of SSIS escaping the backslashes. If you emit the variable's value, you should not see the doubled backslashes.

Comment: Ah I see, yes that is how they are being displayed, so the File System task should interpret them normally then? Meaning that this is not the cause of the problem?

Comment: That'd be my assumption. Can you post a screenshot of how you have your File System Task Configured. Your rep might be too low to auto link the picture but you should be able to paste the url

Comment: can you post your filepath example? or an anonymised version of it?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a ":" in the file path? Looks like that can cause problems. [See related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348768/the-given-paths-format-is-not-supported)

Comment: No there are no "s in the file path

Answer (score 0):

Thats true Dont keep ":" it will works