# Why I am getting "The given path's format is not supported" error

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I am unable to rename a file located in (D drive) using c#. I am getting the error

> Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: The given path's
>   format is not supported.

every time.

I am using

```
string oldfilename = @"D:\abc\file.txt";
string newfilename = @"D:\abc\tree.txt";
System.IO.File.Move(oldfilename, newfilename);
```

but I am getting the error on the last line.
I also tried changing the first 2 lines to

```
string oldfilename = "D:\\abc\\file.txt";
string newfilename = "D:\\abc\\tree.txt";
```

I also ensured that the file "file.txt" exists. Tried to use different location.

I also tried Reading contents of the file.txt, but I am getting same error.
I searched all the Questions on SO, But with no luck I could get this issue resolved. I think there is some issue with the ":" that I am using after the drive letter while specifying the path. Please guide me.

Comment: @TomDoesCode that *might* be a duplicate, but hard to tell if this is the same problem.

Comment: Is that *really* the code? Or did you post a modified version of the actual code?

Comment: That's really the code! Even I am surprised why is it giving that error !

Comment: You are certain it's on that line?  Is the application running on your system or a server/web site?

Comment: ye its on that line. The application is running on my system not on any server.

Comment: @RahulThundrstorm, are you sure that file `D:\abc\file.txt` is not open?

Comment: Did you copy/paste the code from somewhere else? There may be invisible Unicode characters, although the text you posted doesn't seem to have anything strange when checked in a hex viewer

Comment: Can you please check File.Exists(filename) for same and let me know what does it return?

Comment: I can't reproduce this (obviously).  Is `D:` a CD or a mapped networked drive, something that *doesn't* allows renames? Still, that would return a different error

Comment: Try to delete both lines and retype the paths. This should eliminate any unprintable weirdness

Comment: What are the returned values for `oldfilename.IndexOf(':', 2);` and `newfilename.IndexOf(':', 2);` ?

Comment: I have not copy pasted the lines. I have retyped them. Also No files are opened.D: drive is a Local Disk on my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this on another computer but still it didn't work!(Surprising). 
I have managed to solve this issue by moving "file.txt" to my project folder. 
Now I am using

```
string oldfilename = "file.txt";
string newfilename = "tree.txt";
System.IO.File.Move(oldfilename, newfilename);
```

And this Works! 
This doesn't seems to be an answer to this question(for me), but It has really worked for me.

Comment: This doesn't answer anything. Both relative and absolute paths work with File.Move. In fact, if *this* works, it would mean that there were invalid Unicode characters in the folder path (`D:\abc`) but not the file name

Answer (score 0):

Why don´t you utilize:

```
 My.Computer.Filesystem.RenameFile("D:\file.txt", "tree.txt")
```

Answer (score -2):

I try it by myself and these variants worked:

```
        string oldfilename = "C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\WorkTemp\\file.txt";
        string newfilename = "C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\WorkTemp\\file2.txt";
        System.IO.File.Move(oldfilename, newfilename);


        string oldfilename = @"C:\Users\User\Downloads\WorkTemp\file1.txt";
        string newfilename = @"C:\Users\User\Downloads\WorkTemp\file2.txt";
        System.IO.File.Move(oldfilename, newfilename);
```

According to the reference source: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/filestream.cs#749

NotSupportedException will be thrown if the index of the : in your path is at the third position or later. (One would expect : to be the second character) Are you sure there are no zero-width combining characters or other similar Unicode shenanigans going on in your source?
from [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24856821/what-is-causing-notsupportedexception-the-given-paths-format-is-not-supported/24856870#24856870)

Comment: OP already explained that he tried it as a literal ('@') and escaped backslashes.

Comment: Please read the question again. I have already tried this with no luck.

Comment: please mention reference from where you got [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24856870/1196295).

Comment: I have already seen this Question. The : is not at third position.

Comment: Ok, try to create the empty consolse C# project and new empty .txt file 
and write this code.Will it be working?