# Not supported MySQL source of file

Tags: c#, mysql

I've been looking hours for solution, about literal string with @ , changing picture box image etc. In result i'm still stuck and here's my problem

i'm trying to change picture box image with image.fromfile, here's my code

```
string filepath = picturesource.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();

pbTile.Image = Image.FromFile(filepath);
pbTile.Invalidate();
```

picturesource is dataset (select bla bla bla) and returns sources of image

for ex :
‪D:\my project\Semester 3\Software Development\Untitled.png

and in breaks at pbTile.Image line giving me an error :
"The given's path format is not supported"

is there anything wrong with my code or source? i've been looking for hours and didn't find any solution

Thanks guys

**EDIT 1**

Well it seems that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24856821/what-is-causing-notsupportedexception-the-given-paths-format-is-not-supported) has solved my problem
i don't know what makes my colon(:) is on the 3rd place that made windows unsupport the path, what i did is retype the path again on the database and it's fine, seems like there's hidden character between them.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems that this has solved my problem i don't know what makes my colon(:) is on the 3rd place that made windows unsupport the path, what i did is retype the path again on the database and it's fine, seems like there's hidden character between them. thanks