# Copy Tif image to another Folder

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, file, copy

I'm using WinForms. In my form i have a button. When i press that button i want to copy a Tif image to another location and name it display.tif. I've browsed the internet for solutions but they all say use  "Fil.copy()" so i tried that and it keeps giving me an error.

This is my code below:

```
    private void Display_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        File.Copy(@"‪C:\image\Source_File\Display.tif", @"C:\image\Source_File\Destination_File\display.tif", true);

    }
```

and this is the error which i keep on getting. Why do i have this error?

[image]

**Something Interesting i discovered:**

It seems like when you copy and paste the directory from the file properties the code doesn't recognize it even though all the letters look the same. I had to hand write the file path to make it work properly. (right click on the file - the properties should be at the bottom)[image]

Comment: Are you sure the destination path is **C:\image\Source_File\Destination_File\display.tif** and not **C:\image\Destination_File\display.tif** ?

Comment: yes, I am positive. If you copy and paste the path sometimes the code doesn't like it. I found that out the hard way. You have to write the code out manually sometimes.

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24856821/what-is-causing-notsupportedexception-the-given-paths-format-is-not-supported