# An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, unhandled-exception, notsupportedexception

I'm getting the following exception message when trying to use a `StreamWriter`:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

What could be causing this?

[image]

Comment: Have you had a look at the `InnerException`?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .. please do not just post links to pictures. please paste your code.. Your problem seems simple and some simple error trapping would fix the error - its telling you you cant write to the file youve listed

Comment: What does the "Additional Information" say?

Comment: +1, because the exception is not documented, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fysy0a4b(v=vs.110).aspx, but please learn how to ask: include your code as a [mcve], tell us what research you have already done.

Comment: Try a simple path string like `C:\temp\gun1.txt` and ensure the executing context has write access. I suspect it might not like the space.

Comment: additional information says  "The given path format is not supported."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is causing NotSupportedException ("The given path's format is not supported") while using a valid path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24856821/what-is-causing-notsupportedexception-the-given-paths-format-is-not-supported)