# Loading files from directory and add to combo box

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, system.io.directory

I'm currently trying to add whatever files that exist in the directory into a combo box.

```
Dim dir = "‪C:\Users\jason\Desktop\SystemFiles"
For Each file As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir)
    cmbTemplateFiles.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file))
Next
```

When executing this program, it says `The given path's format is not supported`

- Do I have to add new header files?
- Is there anything wrong with my coding?

Comment: Change your 1st line to `Dim dir As String = IO.Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop, "systemfiles")` I'm not sure, but I think this may be a bizarre bug. This line above seems to work fine though.

Comment: The title is wrong, it should be: VB.NET - The given path's format is not supported for System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir)

Comment: Can you break up your question into different parts... i.e. getting a directory's contents and populating items into a combo box and where you're getting stuck in each step?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to reproduce the issue.

I suppose it has to do with your dir string containing invisible, strange characters, like â€ª

Using your snippet, I managed to display them in VS 2017 by putting a breakpoint on the for each line and hover over the "dir" string. I noticed a question mark where the strange characters occur.

My way of resolving this : I downloaded Notepad++ and copied the dir string in a file and via Encoding -> Ansi I managed to display the strange chars. I removed those and copied the string back into VS. Obviously doing this in a different editor might also work.

Retyping the dir manually might also help.
Also refer to [What is causing NotSupportedException ("The given path's format is not supported") while using a valid path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24856821/what-is-causing-notsupportedexception-the-given-paths-format-is-not-supported)

Comment: Good catch :-).