# The given path's is not supported C#

Tags: c#, file-io, path

I have an strange problem I have an app that scan a directory and gets a list of files.  it processes each file by reading it and doing some stuff.  it works fine in the development computer but when I deploy it to the client it gives me the error.  Here is the code

```
public void ProcessIMFiles()
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Globals.ITMDIR);
        FileInfo[] Files = di.GetFiles("*.txt");            
        foreach(FileInfo file in Files)
        {
            try
            {
                processThisIMFile(file.FullName);
                movefile(file.FullName);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error : " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

The error happens in the call to processThisIMFile(file.FullName)  see below.
Globals.ITMDIR is a valid path.

```
private void processThisIMFile(string FileName)
    {
        string[] Fields = null;
        setconnection();
        DataTable dt = null;
        try
        {
            string[] Lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(FileName);

            foreach (string line in Lines)
            {
                Fields = line.Split(Globals.delimiter);
                if (Fields.Length == 7)
                {
                   //stuff happens here
                }
        }//Try
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (Interactive)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error in the Path: ->" + FileName);
                writeToLog(true, "error opening file " + FileName);
            }
        }
    }//end of processThisItemFile
```

the error happens in the "string[] Lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(FileName)"
line. FileName comes from the di.GetFiles("*.txt"); when I show the actual path it looks ok to me.  I have tried with UNC paths and with drive letters path as in C:\tmp\filename.txt or \\server\tmp\filename.txt both fail in the deplopyment machine with "The given path's is not supported" but it works fine in the development machine.

What is going on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348768/the-given-paths-format-is-not-supported

Comment: Maybe some logs is needed. log `FileName` in `processThisIMFile`

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if this could be related to file.fullname somehow altering the file path string and giving an unacceptable result. Can you troubleshoot by using `processThisIMFile(Path.GetFullPath(file))`? Also, use `messagebox.show(file.FullName)` prior to processthisimfile to confirm that the result is as expected.