# Rename to folder with tilde symbol

Tags: c#, rename, tilde

I know the method `Directory.Move(source, destination)` to rename a folder. But when I rename the desitnation folder with the `~` symbol at the begin, there is error.

> System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported.

Here is my code:

```cs
string oldFolderPath = @"C:\Old";
string newFolderPath = "~" + oldFolderPath;
Directory.Move(oldFolderPath, newFolderPath);
```

In the `System.IO.Path.InvalidPathChars`, the following characters are invalid:
`" < > |`

It does not list tilde symbol, so how can I do? Thank you very much.

Comment: The `~` is used in 8.3 paths (like dos, 8 characters + 3 extension), Windows uses it internally for the 8.3 names of folder/file names > 8 characters. I guess that's the reason why you can't use it.

Comment: possibly Path.Combine is what u need to use here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348768/the-given-paths-format-is-not-supported

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tilde is perfectly valid in a folder name. Your code sample doesn't show what value `demoPath` has but, since tilde is valid in the folder name, you're probably doing something like appending it to the start of the path and not where you intended to.

E.g. **not like** this: `~C:\Old` but `C:\~Old`.

Comment: Ah ha. I forgot that, it should be `C:\~Old` instead of `~C:\Old`. Thank you very much!!!