# Why am I getting "path's format not supported error"?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to change button image. **Image which I want after button click event is given full access.**
Code given below is on buttonclick event.

```
Image i1 = Image.FromFile(@"‪E:\TEMP\BeautyParlour\BeautyParlour\Resources\Done.png");
button6.Image = null;
button6.Image = i1;
```

After running application when I click on button it gives me following error:

> The given path's format is not supported.

With the exception as:

> NotSupportedException was unhandled

Comment: What did you try? Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7348799/11867443) could help you...

Comment: Add the image to the project resources and then you can directly assign the image.

Comment: If you must use a file path you should check that the app can see it. This error comes from either the file not being there or no permissions from what I can tell. Invisible characters in the path can also cause it.

Comment: Copy/pasting the path from the Explorer address bar [might get you more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24856821/what-is-causing-notsupportedexception-the-given-paths-format-is-not-supported) than you think.  You never want to do this anyway, odds that the user of your program has an e:\temp directory are too low.

Comment: @aziui I visited that link already but its little bit complex to understand considering i just want to import  one image but thanks :)

Comment: @MikeCheel I do gave full control of image as i stated it in my briefing of problem and for invisible spaces I copied the path from **properties / security TAB**

Comment: @HansPassant I totally agree with you considering I must group all necessary resources in project cause odds are 100% no :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding the images you are using to the project resources. For example below I have added two images `Add.png` and `Ok.png` to my project

[image: pic1]

The to use the image, just assign it to the button

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Image = Properties.Resources.Ok;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks error is gone but still its not showing image, its just only showing me text of my button

Comment: IDK without any other information. Check the image align and text-align properties on the button and if the image shows up in the resources it should be visible on the UI also.