# How can I pass a string variable through the soundplayer?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to pass the file location from my list box into my sound player.

```
string fileLocation = listBox1.ToString();
SoundPlayer splayer = new SoundPlayer(soundLocation: fileLocation);
splayer.Play();
```

debugging shows the variable coming through as "C:\Temp\Sample1.wav".

The error comes back as "System.NotSupportedException: 'The given path's format is not supported.'"

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Is there a question here? What is the problem you're running in to? It looks like you're already passing the file path as a string in to the constructor successfully.

Comment: sorry i missed a bit off :-)

Comment: Sounds like the file path string isn't formatted properly and/or has some funky characters that aren't supported. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348768/the-given-paths-format-is-not-supported

Comment: @tnw thanks so much that looks like the issue. I'll try it out

Comment: @tnw thanks mate, your direction wasn't quite what I needed. But it directed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cracked it! you need to pull the object then convert it to a string.

```
        object fileLocationobj = listBox1.Items[0];
        string fileLocation = fileLocationobj.ToString(); 
        SoundPlayer splayer = new SoundPlayer(soundLocation: fileLocation);
        splayer.Play()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).